# updating a python dict with the help of value from a sensor

Tags: python, list, sensors, lidar

I have a python script to run a Lidar sensor. It measures distance. I am moving the lidar with the help of Servo motors. So i have to measure the distance at different angle. I am trying the update a dict with angle and distance. But the dict always show wrong angle values.

Part of the code is given below. Any kind of suggestions would be really helpful

```
    angle_start =0
    angle_step = 2    #degree step     
    self.set_angle(angle_start)   #a method to set servo angle
    time.sleep(pos_time) 

    angle_dict = {}          #an empty dict
    angle=angle_start
    while angle <= angle_stop:

        self.set_angle(angle)
        time.sleep(0.05)

        distance = int(self.messure_distance())    #a method to measure the distance. it works fine.
        angle_dict[angle] = distance       #trying to update the dict. it stores right distance. but now the right angle.

        angle = angle + angle_step              #increasing angle
```

Comment: What angle values does it show and which values did you expect? Please construct a [MCVE]. You can insert dummies/placeholders for unrelated API functions like `measure_distance` etc.